# Unknown scripts are prepending before html body close tag

Tags: javascript, malware

From today morning, i found some unknown scripts are prepending just before the       "body" close tag, The scripts are :

```
<script> var addthis_config = {"pubid":"ra-554ac5c71847b3c2"}; </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-554ac5c71847b3c2"></script>
<script> if (addthis && addthis.layers) { addthis.layers({'share':{'mobile':false}});}</script>
```

I had not added this piece of code to the website. I was searching for the root cause for this. But until this moment i cannot find a solution to remove this script. What i did/observed so far :

**Removed "body" close tag :** No script

**Tried to add an html file(with basic tags) index.html file :** found the script is injected right before the body close.

**Scripts are only seen at the home page.**

**The files uploaded to different hosting with a different domain :** No scripts

The web server is Apache, and the content of .htaccess is as shown below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite\.ae [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The website is hosted with Amazon Web services. Does anyone have such an experience before ?

Comment: Do you have the AddThis extension in your browser? (firefox/chrome)?

Comment: @Dekel, no. i can see this script in the page source, Im using laravel 4.2

Comment: Does it happen only in your domain? Did you try to fetch the url not from your pc? (try http://web-sniffer.net)

Comment: yes only from the specific domain, i tried uploading the same files to a different hosting associated with another domain & the script is not shown there

Comment: and the second part of my comment?

Comment: Yes tried on 4 different PC. the result is same

Comment: So it might be some malicious code in your server

Comment: You could run some code of your own that watch the DOM for changes, then you might be able to notice the script tags being added and return the stack trace to find the source of origin.

Comment: @GillesC, if that code exists in the source (and it shouldn't be there), its coming directly from the server. If the file in the server was clean (and still clean on the server), it means that someone interfere with the output of the request), so it's not really related to DOM changes.

Comment: If i move the entire website from the root to a sub folder, there will be no script tags .

Comment: Which http server are you using? Do you you see a file named `.htaccess` in your root folder? If so - what's its content? (add to the question, not as a comment)

Comment: @Dekel question updated

Comment: Is there any chance to get a link to the domain? (just for a quick check, you can delete that comment later on)

Comment: maybe you turned on some option in amazon panel to enable addThis service

Comment: addThis is a service that comes very often as plugin that self inject scripts in code. Maybe you set that somewhere in AWS or more probably you have some plugin installed that automaticly add this to your code (very often on wordpress).
Search in your code and dependencies for 'addthis_config' and you will probabgly find what is cousing that.

Comment: @MichałIgnaszewski, I made a search with in the entire project folder for the texts "addthis", "ra-554ac5c71847b3c2" etc. I cannot find any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause !! 
Actually the page was served via a different IP rather than the real hosting IP(May be a DNS attack ?). I found this while inspecting the header under the developer tools ->Response header :

> via : Stark 1.0 (Something like this).

Then I tried The public IP of the AWS hosting & the scrip was not appearing at all.But if i try to load the website by domain name, This Via header is set. So i informed the domain registrar about this issue, dont know how they fixed this issue.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.addthis.com/academy/the-addthis_config-variable/

Either the page you are viewing is using addThis, or a third party script is adding it.

If this is your page, and you want to find out whic page is adding it, put this code at the top of your page

```
document.createElement = (function () {
   var _realCE = document.createElement;
   return function (name,options) {
      if (name.toLowerCase() === 'script') {
         try {
            throw "script added to page";
         }
         catch(e) {
            console.warn(e.message);
            console.warn(e.stack);
         }
      }
      return _realCE.apply(document,arguments);
   }
})();
```

It will spit out a stack trace anytime a script creates another script tag. This should give you enough to figure out which script is doing this to you.

Comment: I would suggest @PatrickDenny approach to filter what is being loaded.

Comment: I tested the output with this code & found more scripts are appending to the DOM, i believe that something is infected the server.. PLease see the logs, Original files, & the modified DOM here ->> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxzpM4eCPCYKNkhyYnBkWjAwUEE

Comment: Few things I would check to be sure nothing else is loaded automatically. 1.) Clear the Web Browser Cache and delete everything from beginning of time. 2.) Move the problematic file into different folder and verify for same result. 3.) Disconnect internet connection and load on localhost to verify for same result. I'm interested to know the result in this step #3. 4.) If problem continues, set a breakpoint in your HTML file between opening and closing script and step into breakpoint for clues with firebug.

Comment: @Shan - Addthis is a Social Sharing plugin, it is by no means malware. It's there because someone who was working on that site wanted it there (or didn't know what they were doing when they put it there). You can rest assured that nothing is "infected" lol...

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I agree with you completely regarding The Addthis plugin. But, The same files uploaded to a different hosting, doesnt have these issue( i wrote this in my question)!, I suspect something is infected, because, I just wrote the DOM content to a file, before returning to the view of Laravel, & i found the DOM is clean with out these scripts

Comment: @jmsweb, i tried these, even from different 4 pcs, No clues from the breakpoints too :(

Comment: Do a full system scan for "addthis_widget.js". You might may to run with keyword like "addthis" or "addthis_widget". I'm under assumption somewhere in your system or server is doing automatic integration and that was caused by installed plugin of some sort.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and suggest to disconnect your media accounts from Amazon Web: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/getting-started.html#start-service. I think no media account shouldn't produce any social shares.

Comment: ive not used amazon but i know cpanel has options to turn on certain plugins that inject code before serving. I believe something similar is turned on in your amazon control panel. That is the only thing that makes any sense imo. I would start with calling amazon hostimg tech support. I know hostgator would have had this figured out and fixed in no time.

Comment: @patrick Thanks for your script, even though this doesnt solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in comments:

> yes only from the specific domain, i tried uploading the same files to
>   a different hosting associated with another domain & the script is not
>   shown there

**What is adding this script to website?**

Your hosting want to get more visitors, so adding this plug-in inside your webpage.

**What this plug-in doing?**

This plug-in is creating links to social sites and other links... so if you are searching you website on google you can side more than you have on your page, like social links, etc. You can read about it [here](http://www.addthis.com/).

**What to do to prevent this?**

You can see or download script at [this address](http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js). If you are using any free hosting, it is usually why do you have this "ads" in you website, else if you have normal paid hosting try to contact support and ask why do you have this script on website or try to deactivate it in website admin.